# Runtime Error 201 when adding a const string to a variable PASCAL

Tags: arrays, runtime, pascal, julian-date

Hello I have been given the task of reading file input of 3 digit month abbreviations and a day and I must calculate the Julian date for each (sum of days since jan 1)
No matter what I do when I add two INTEGERS I get error 201 (incompatible data types). I have tried making a new program and gotten it to work but once I implement it into my existing code it doesn't work anymore. This is very frustrating, please help. I'm sick of this stupid class making me take this language where I can't find shit online to help.
Here is the code:

```
program prg6_150;
const
      MONABV:array[1..12] of string[03] = ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN',
                                           'JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC');
      MONDAYS:array[1..12] of integer = (31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

var
      more_rec:Boolean;                    { EOF flag }
      DAY:integer;                         { input day }
      MONTH:string[03];                    { input month abbreviation }
      JULIAN:integer;                      { computed Julian day }
      ch:char;                             { spacer character for input }
      FileIn:Text;
      FileOut:Text;

{ your module, to be called "JULIAN_DAY" inserted here }


    procedure JULIAN_DAY;
    var
    j,sum_days:integer;
    begin
    j := 0;
    sum_days := 0;
    if MONTH = 'JAN' then j := 1 else
    if MONTH = 'FEB' then j := 2 else
    if MONTH = 'MAR' then j := 3 else
    if MONTH = 'APR' then j := 4 else
    if MONTH = 'MAY' then j := 5 else
    if MONTH = 'JUN' then j := 6 else
    if MONTH = 'JUL' then j := 7 else
    if MONTH = 'AUG' then j := 8 else
    if MONTH = 'SEP' then j := 9 else
    if MONTH = 'OCT' then j := 10 else
    if MONTH = 'NOV' then j := 11 else
    if MONTH = 'DEC' then j := 12; 
    for J:= 2 to 12 do
    repeat
        sum_days := MONDAYS[1] + sum_days;
        j := j - 1
    until j = 1;
    Julian := DAY + sum_days;
    end;

    procedure read_rec;
    begin
      if Eof(FileIn) then
        more_rec := False
      else
        readln(FileIn,day,ch,month)
    end;  { read_rec }

    procedure initialize;
    begin
      more_rec := True;
      Assign(FileIn,'JULIAN.DAT');
      Reset(FileIn);
      Assign(FileOut,'JULIAN.OUT');
      Rewrite(FileOut);
      read_rec
    end;  { initialize }

    procedure process;
    begin
      Julian_Day;
      writeln(FileOut,day:2,' ',month,' ',julian:3);
      read_rec
    end;  { process }

    procedure wrapup;
    begin
      Close(FileOut);
      Close(FileIn)
    end;  { wrapup }

    begin  { main }
      initialize;
      while more_rec do
        process;
      wrapup
    end.
```

[Command Prompt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3rer.png)

Comment: MONDAYS[1] is normally MONDAYS[j-1], I temporarily edited to try and it still gave me a type error hurr durr

Answer (score 1):

Runtime error 201 does not mean `incompatible types`! It means `Range check error` as [documented](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html#x190-197000D):

> 201 Range check error If you compiled your program with range checking
>   on, then you can get this error in the following cases:
>
> 1.An array was accessed with an index outside its declared range.
>
> 2.Trying to assign a value to a variable outside its range (for instance an enumerated type).

Another error in your code is that you change the `for loop` control varable `j` within the loop. That is not allowed. You must leave the control variable alone, and use a separate variable that you can change as needed.

You need to rethink your nested `for loop` and `repeat .. until`. Maybe the mess was created in trial and error attempts to fix the 201 error.